# Marshal managed to unmanaged array of unsigned ints

Tags: c++, c++-cli, command-line-interface, marshalling

I have managed array of unsigned ints:

```
array<unsigned int> ^intParams
```

I have native function that takes as argument:

```
const unsigned int *intParams
```

I was trying using Marshal::Copy like this:

```
IntPtr ptr_intParams = Marshal::AllocHGlobal( intParams->Length * sizeof( unsigned int ) );
Marshal::Copy( intParams, 0, ptr_intParams, intParams->Length );
```

but it seems like Marshal::Copy is not supporting unsigned types (?)

How can I correctly convert this managed array to unmanaged?

Comment: You'd normally strongly favor using `pin_ptr<>` so you don't need a copy at all.  The native code then gets a pointer into the managed array, pointing to the first element in the array.  Much like the way it works in a C program.  The array is pinned as long as the pin_ptr variable is in scope so nothing bad can happen while the native code runs.   But if the native code stores that pointer and uses it later then you must make a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array conversion is a common problem in C++/CLI, and hence has an elegant solution: `pin_ptr<>`. Use it this way:

```
array<unsigned int> ^intParams;
// code that assigns a managed array to intParams
pin_ptr<unsigned int> intParamsPtr = &intParams [0];
// code that uses intParamsPtr as unsigned int*
```

Note that this code doesn't involve any coyping of elements. It just puts a pointer to the beginning of the managed array and "pins" it, so it cannot be moved around in memory during garbage collection. Luckily, the layout of integer arrays - signed, unsigned, and of any element size - is the same on the managed and unmanaged side, so there's no need for element conversion.

The pinned pointer is valid only in the block where it is defined. As soon as it goes out of scope (e.g. after a closing curly brace), the pointer becomes invalid automatically. There's no need to dispose of the pointer.

Comment: You are right. I don't need to copy it, because I don't store this pointer in native code.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, It was simple...
I've managed to do it like this:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> vec_intParams( intParams->Length );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < vec_intParams.size( ); ++i )
    vec_intParams[i] = intParams[i];
```

...and later in code when I want to use pointer I just make this:

```
vec_intParams.data( )
```

Comment: Copying the values in a for-loop certainly is the least performant way to solve this conversion problem. See my answer below for the proper solution.

Comment: You are right. I don't need to copy it. I've changed right answer. Thansk!